# Facing Memory Error with Plenty of Available Memory

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, out-of-memory

I'm working on a research project which involves loading a plethora of 256x256 image patches. I continuously face a memory error on this code cell, when I am loading the data into a PyTorch data class:

```
train_data = Patch_Class("train", train_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_augmentation)
val_data = Patch_Class("val", val_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_normal)
test_data = Patch_Class("test", test_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_normal)
```

However, it appears that lots of memory is still available when I run the `psutil.virtual_memory()` command.

Output of the `psutil.virtual_memory()` command before running cell:

```
svmem(total=134886518784, available=101604401152, percent=24.7, used=31880663040, free=21492129792, active=44802818048, inactive=60591763456, buffers=20480, cached=81513705472, shared=759042048, slab=3532451840)
```

Output of the `psutil.virtual_memory()` command after running cell and facing the error:

```
svmem(total=134886518784, available=83156258816, percent=38.4, used=50329522176, free=3005030400, active=63661797376, inactive=60169121792, buffers=20480, cached=81551945728, shared=759037952, slab=3540103168)
```

Here is the full error that I am facing for reference:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/scratch/ipykernel_6018/3059984817.py in <module>
----> 1 train_data = Patch_Class("train", train_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_augmentation)
      2 val_data = Patch_Class("val", val_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_normal)
      3 test_data = Patch_Class("test", test_df, s_df, transform=preprocess_normal)

/scratch/ipykernel_6018/1627651323.py in __init__(self, set_type, slides_df, meta_df, transform)
     10         self.data_dic = {} #get the mapping between WSI id and np array
     11 
---> 12         self.build_dic()
     13 
     14     def build_dic(self):

/scratch/ipykernel_6018/1627651323.py in build_dic(self)
     15         for idx, row in tqdm(self.meta_df.iterrows()):
     16             if row["set"] == self.set_type:
---> 17                 self.data_dic[row["IDs"]] = np.load(row["npy_loc"])
     18 
     19     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/Ashank/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    439             else:
    440                 return format.read_array(fid, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
--> 441                                          pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    442         else:
    443             # Try a pickle

~/anaconda3/envs/Ashank/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py in read_array(fp, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    755         if isfileobj(fp):
    756             # We can use the fast fromfile() function.
--> 757             array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)
    758         else:
    759             # This is not a real file. We have to read it the

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.27 GiB for an array with shape (3510632448,) and data type uint8
```

I have tried other data loading techniques including saving all the image patches to a Numpy array and have been able to easily use around 85% of the data before facing this error. Is there any reason why it is throwing the error with so much memory available? Thanks